# MySQL error when trying to truncate table

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems to truncate a table on the MySQL Server 5.5.

The table I'm trying to truncate has a column that serves as a foreign key in another table.

The `CREATE TABLE` of both tables involved is as it follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbluser` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `creationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `creationUserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updateDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updateUserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastAccess` datetime NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
  KEY `FK_tbluser_creationUserId` (`creationUserId`),
  KEY `FK_tbluser_updateUserId` (`updateUserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tbluser_updateUserId` FOREIGN KEY (`updateUserId`) REFERENCES `tbluser` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tbluser_creationUserId` FOREIGN KEY (`creationUserId`) REFERENCES `tbluser` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `tblpost` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `creationDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1901-01-01 00:00:00',
  `creationUserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updateDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1901-01-01 00:00:00',
  `updateUserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_tblpost_creationUserId` (`creationUserId`),
  KEY `FK_tblpost_updateUserId` (`updateUserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tblpost_updateUserId` FOREIGN KEY (`updateUserId`) REFERENCES `tbluser` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tblpost_creationUserId` FOREIGN KEY (`creationUserId`) REFERENCES `tbluser` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Please note that all the constraints are both set to `DELETE` and `UPDATE ON CASCADE`.

When I try to `TRUNCATE` the table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `<databasename>`.`tbluser`;
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
(`<databasename>`.`tblpost`, 
CONSTRAINT `FK_tblpost_updateUserId` 
FOREIGN KEY (`updateUserId`) 
REFERENCES `<databasename>`.`tbluser` (`id`))
```

In addition to this information, there is the fact that when the action above is attempted on a MySQL Server 5.1, it works!

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58788) . That makes sense that `TRUNCATE TABLE` raises an error in such cases; the bad thing that it's not documented.

Comment: The problem with the error is the fact that we've set to DELETE ON CASCADE. I believe that the expected behavior is the one we get on the Server 5.1 where it TRUNCATES the specified table and deletes all the data on the other tables where the FK is set. 
Sure that makes almost like a "complete truncate" of the database, but i did specified to DELETE ON CASCADE, and that's what it should do, isn't?

Comment: We've made tests on the project and in fact there is no "easy" way out. If we follow the specified solution and disable the ForeignKeys Notifications, whenever a row is deleted on the User's table, nothing happens on the tblpost, and that is wrong.

We've decided to keep all our MySQL Servers on the same version to avoid more problems such as these.

Thanks to a1ex07 for the bull's eye help!

Comment: I believe they should have said something like "you cannot truncate table referenced by FK" somewhere in documentation to clear all misunderstandings. It seems to me that they rather had a bug in previous versions which made `TRUNCATE` work similar to `DELETE` with no `WHERE` when it comes to FK. I realize it's quite controversial opinion, but my thought here is that `TRUNCATE` should involve less overhead compared to `DELETE` and doesn't have to take care about FK constraint.